# DataGridView/ListView - Display in an Outlook style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm used to using Telerik Grids and I'm able to display them in an outlook style, i.e. a picture on the far left, a bold title and a few other lines of text under the main title.

Is there a way do this using a standard .Net2.0 Windows control? Either with a cheap control, or the existing datagridview or listview?

Basically, I need to be able to produce a layout as follows:

```
Job Title
Engineer: Fred Bloggs
Product: Some random product
```

So, I'll have 2000 or so of these items in a grid  with a status image next to each of them, what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is help with using a listview for the list.  I would go with the list because you will only have one column, so no need for the grid.

You want to use :

```
private void lstItems_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
```

Then use the e.Graphics to get an object you can draw directly to.

I used this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/1930110286_10.aspx) to help me learn about drawing in the ListView

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an example as I don't have time to write it at this time, but you could create a UserControl which lays out the row as you would like to see it. Then you would have to create your own DataGridViewCell which can handle a UserControl rather than the standard cell types which MS provides. For each of your entries, create and fill the user control and add it to another row in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing.  I just came across something interesting.  Check out the free Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0 (you can reference this from any .NET language including c#):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb735936.aspx

It basically let's you design a single row with whatever controls you want and then repeats that row with your bound data